# Windows 10 Boots Automatically After Installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 from a LiveUSB, and the install went well. However, my system always boots into Windows. `boot-repair` does not help in my case. How can I fix this?

[BootRepair Log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12210726)

Comment: What model PC do you have?

Comment: HP Pavilion TS Sleekbook 15

Comment: It came with windows 8 sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Hold ESC during startup, then press F9 to select a boot device. Ubuntu should show up there. Once you've booted into Ubuntu, open a terminal and enter `sudo efibootmgr`. Please add the output to your question so we can give you more help. (If efibootmgr isn't installed, use `sudo apt-get install efibootmgr` and then try again.)

Comment: What error (if any) is thrown by boot-repair ? Or does the boot-repair succeed ?

Comment: Yes, that's important to know. Also, what options did you use in boot-repair? Did you use the recommended repair? Do you have a URL from the results?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the boot order on your laptop.

The [manual for your computer](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03660406.pdf) (HP Pavilion TS Sleekbook 15) says to follow these instructions:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and turn on your computer.
3. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to enter your BIOS Settings.
4. Navigate to **System Configuration**.
5. Navigate to **Boot Option**
6. Move the Ubuntu entry to the top of the list.

Comment: For most HP pavilion's, the boot order options only let you change which *device* gets booted first, not which bootloader.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann It uses a legacy BIOS?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann - Your BIOS should allow you to select which OS to boot, usually in the boot menu, sometime under security or secure boot or (U)EFI boot, it varies. If this is NOT AN OPTION, try updating your BIOS and contacting HP (HP is better then most with Linux support, although not perfect).

Comment: It has UEFI firmware, but it does have a legacy option for supporting operating systems designed for BIOS firmware. My laptop's the year-older model of the asker's, but I've spent a few weeks getting it to dual-boot, and not being able to specify the OS from the firmware menu is a big hangup for people with similar hardware in lots of forums. @Jack Li probably needs to change the boot order using efibootmgr, if he installed out of legacy mode (in regular UEFI mode), or he might be able to use bcdedit within Windows to change/add a boot entry for GRUB to Windows Boot Manager if in legacy.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, updating the firmware does not fix this, and HP says it's how it should be. I disagree :)

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann is right, I can only specify OS Boot Manager in the boot order, not the OS. I have no idea what to do now

Comment: Jack, did you install in legacy mode? Also, is Secure Boot enabled? (They're both on the same settings page as the boot order.)

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann Well I think it's in regular UEFI mode, because I didn't change the settings. Secure Boot is enabled.

Comment: OK. That makes things easier. Can you give us the output of `sudo efibootmgr`?

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann `BootCurrent: 0002 Timeout: 0 seconds BootOrder: 3000, 3002, 3003, 2001, 2002, 2003 Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager Boot0002* Ubuntu Boot0003* Ubuntu Boot2001 USB Drive(UEFI) Boot3000 Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk Boot3002: "" Boot3003: ""`

Comment: There's your problem. Entry 3000 is set to boot first. That's your hard drive, so Windows must just be the first bootloader in your hard drive's MBR. Try `sudo efibootmgr -o 0002,0000,2001,3000` . Reboot, and let us know if that works.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann I just tried that, and it returned the new boot order, but Windows still booted. It seems pretty resilient :( Well I actually didn't know I could boot Ubuntu manually through f9, so I guess that works for me. I don't particularly need it every time I restart. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, the question isn't answered, but you're welcome. If you want to persist, the next step is to use Grub Customizer to make sure Windows is not the default entry (if it's there). Grub defaults to a timeout of 0 seconds, so it selects the default entry instantly after installation. (At least that's how it's behaved after several recent  reinstalls.) There are also more things you can try- you could add an entry for GRUB to Windows Boot Manager using bcdedit, then set it's displaybootmenu to Yes, and its timeout to something more than 0 so you can just use Windows' boot menu instead of GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this command in Command Prompt (NOT powershell) as administrator:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```